# CreateElement doesn't create any element in my xml file

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm playing with an xml file trying to manipulate it. The code runs fine with no errors, but it doesnt actually write anything in the xml file.

```
function addDogDetails() {
var xmlDoc = xmlLoader("dogs.xml");

var newel=xmlDoc.createElement("dog");

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("dogHouse")[0];
x.appendChild(newel);
}
```

the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dogHouse>
    <dog>
        <dogName>Shaggy</dogName>
    </dog>
</dogHouse>
```

Is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: Is this in a browser? Is it IE/Windows?

Comment: What makes you think that making a change to the DOM obtained by parsing an XML file will have any affect at all on the original file?

Comment: @Pointy - yes exactly. However if IE/Windows there _may_ be a way to access the file system with ActiveX magic or something - worth checking.

Comment: Yes, I accept that there may be some way to write the DOM back out to the file, but I see no trace of that in the code posted :-)

Comment: i did some more research, i thought there was something wrong with the code, but i found out that it does work but not the way i understood it. I thought it should write to the actual file but in fact it write to memory. And using save() writes to the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [createNode()](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/quickref/document_createNode.html)

Comment: Not really. `createElement()` is standard DOM (unlike the proprietary Microsoft `createNode()`)  and works on XML DOMs in all major browsers, so is a better option unless you need to set a namespace for the element.